# Android Studio Polyline gradient Not working

Tags: android, kotlin

When I try to make a gradient polyline using `StyleSpan(StrokeStyle.gradientBuilder(Color.RED,Color.GREEN).build())` but it will return only black color. Kindly share your guidance

I need to draw gradient route in map kindly share your knowledge

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable the use of StyleSpan you have to initializate your map with latest render. If not, the legacy is set for default and that render doesn't include this option.
To do this at the begining of the onCreate fun add the following line:

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(applicationContext,Render.LATEST, this)
```

It is important to call it before any MapView, MapFragment, or SupportMapFragment has been created

You can also implement the following function to check which version are you using.

```
override fun onMapsSdkInitialized(renderer: MapsInitializer.Renderer) {
     when (renderer) {
       Renderer.LATEST -> Log.d("MapsDemo", "The latest version of the renderer is used.")
       Renderer.LEGACY -> Log.d("MapsDemo", "The legacy version of the renderer is used.")
     }    }
```

More information about this is availabe https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer